# PHP Switch - view only one case?

Tags: php, joomla, switch-statement, case

At the moment i have a form that has two select options, one that can view case 0 and one with case 4.

I got a tab, so i cant use a form, because the site refresh when i choose one option. And then it shows that options in  both tabs.

I've tried to only have one options. But that dont work to.

This is the tab/form code:

```
<div class="tab1">
<form action="<?php  echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_yoflash" />
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="category" />
<input type="hidden" name="mochicat" value="<?php echo $this->cat->catid; ?>" />
<select name="order" size="1" onchange="submit();">
  <option value="0" <?php if($this->order=="0") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>><?php echo JText::_('ORDER_DATE_NEWEST'); ?></option>
  <option value="4" <?php if($this->order=="4") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>><?php echo JText::_('ORDER_POPULAR'); ?></option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $this->Itemid; ?>" />
</form>
</div>
```

And i got another div tab thats exactly the same. In the first div tab i want to view the case 0 or the order 0.

And in the second div tab i want to view case4 or order 4. But i dont want to have any form just view that order. instead of selecting via the form.

This is the switch code:

```
$limitstart=JRequest::getInt('limitstart',0);
    if($order==-1) {
      $tmp=$session->get('order');
      if(empty($tmp)) {
        $order=0;
      }
      else {
        $order=$session->get('order');
      }
    }
    $session->set('order',$order);


    $order=$session->get('order');
    $Itemid=JRequest::getInt('Itemid',NULL);

    switch($order){
      case 0:
        $str="ORDER BY date_added DESC";
        break;
      case 1:
        $str="ORDER BY date_added ASC";
        break;
      case 2:
        $str="ORDER BY name ASC";
        break;
      case 3:
        $str="ORDER BY name DESC";
        break;
      case 4:
        $str="ORDER BY stat_clicked DESC";
        break;
      default:
        $str="ORDER BY date_added ASC";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you have two selections, where the second depends on the first? If user selects something in the fist, the web-app should update the second? Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, this is what i want.

First off, I am editing a component. Originally it is a form that views a list of what order i want to view the games in.

But i want a tab menu instead. One with NEW GAMES and the second one with POPULAR GAMES.

So i created the tab menu/system. and then just added the code to each div. So they have the same code and forms. But when I am in ex. tab 1 (NEW GAMES) and choose from the selected list order by date. it views all the newest games. But when i shit to the other tab (POPULAR GAMES) it has changed to, to view the newsest games. It like the inherit each other.

This is the whole code for the tabs:

```
    <div class="tab">
    <h2><a name="newgames" id="newgames">a</a></h2>

<form action="<?php  echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_yoflash" />
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="category" />
<input type="hidden" name="mochicat" value="<?php echo $this->cat->catid; ?>" />
<select name="order" size="1" onchange="submit();">
<option value="0" <?php if($this->order=="0") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>><?php echo JText::_('ORDER_DATE_NEWEST'); ?></option>
<option value="4" <?php if($this->order=="4") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>><?php echo JText::_('ORDER_POPULAR'); ?></option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $this->Itemid; ?>" />
</form>



 <?php
///////////////////////////////////////
// GAMES BOXES START
///////////////////////////////////////
  $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

  for($i=0;$i<count($this->games);$i++) {
  $game=$this->games[$i];
  $slug=$game->slug;

  $game->imgname=$this->params->get('dir_swf').$slug.'/'.$game->imgname;
  $game->description=$db->getEscaped($game->description);
  $game->description=str_replace("\\\"","\'",$game->description);
  $game->namett=$db->getEscaped($game->name);
  ?>

<div class="game" style="display:block;">

<a style="border:0;" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php/play?option=com_yoflash&view=game&id='.$slug.'&Itemid='.$this->Itemid); ?>" onmouseover="Tip('<strong><?php echo $game->namett; ?></strong><br/> <?php echo $game->description; ?>',WIDTH,300,FADEIN,0,DELAY,0,BGCOLOR, '<?php echo $this->params->get('ttip_bgcolor'); ?>', BORDERCOLOR,'<?php echo $this->params->get('ttip_bordercolor'); ?>',FONTCOLOR,'<?php echo $this->params->get('ttip_fontcolor'); ?>',FONTSIZE,'<?php echo $this->params->get('ttip_fontsize'); ?>',FONTFACE,'<?php echo $this->params->get('ttip_fontface'); ?>')" onmouseout="UnTip()">
<img src="<?php echo $game->imgname; ?>" width="71" height="56" alt="<?php echo $game->name; ?>"/><br/>
<div class="gameName"><?php echo "<p>$game->name</p>"; ?></div>
</a>

<span class="info"><?php echo $game->description; ?></span>

 <span class="gamePlayed"><?php echo "<p>$game->stat_clicked <br/></p>".JText::_("<p> plays</p>") ;?></span> 

 </div>
```

In this tab(NEWEST GAMES) i only want to view the newest games

And the other tab (POPULAR GAMES) looks exactly alike.

Hopes describes more?

Comment: I guess what is happening is that the sort parameter you are sending to the database is the same for both tabs, so the information in both is sorted in the same way.  so what you need is two sorting params such as $sort_new and $sort_popular and set them both individually using the same logic, but reading from different parameters in the $_GET, does that make sense ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not so good in php, so i dont know how to write that..:(

Comment: well, in my last answer where I put $_POST["sort"] perhaps you can swap with $_GET["sort_new"] and $_GET["sort_popular"] and the bottom part where it selects the SQL using one of those $_GET parameters in different tabs?

Comment: Yes, but what do i write in those tabs divs to get that $order = $_GET["sort_newgames"];
?

Comment: well, it's complicated, depends on your exact circumstances and almost impossible to help you in the comments I could make on this site.  I suggest you learn how PHP and HTML work together in order to solve it, but it's not an easy question I can enter in 500 characters, plus the answer would require you understand PHP/HTML, so you are stuck anyway :( sorry

Answer (score 5):

ewww, the switch is a bit ugly, here is a nicer version:

```
$sortMap = array(
"ORDER BY date_added DESC",
"ORDER BY date_added ASC",
"ORDER BY name ASC",
"ORDER BY name DESC",
"ORDER BY stat_clicked DESC"
);

$str = isset($sortMap[$order]) 
    ? $sortMap[$order]
    : "ORDER BY date_added ASC";
```

since $order is between 0..4 you might as well exploit the fact that it will map to array indexes and avoid the ugly switch and save yourself a bunch of wasted, cluttered lines in the process.

note: you could also do this with an associative array if $type doesn't conform to normal numeric array indexes, you'd just specify the array index in each element manually like "cat"=>"ORDER BY..." in your sort map array and it should work identically.

Comment: This answer does not apply to the question. Nevertheless, I like your proposal technically.

Comment: Thanks, but what do i do to view that order, other then having a form to select?

Comment: yeah I realise that I don't actually answer the question, just clean up the code :/

Comment: I just added a new answer factoring in what you asked, I added a html select and a way to select the appropriate SQL from the array, is this better?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to my above answer, I think what you want is to show a [select] html dropdown where you can "pick" a sort order and that will pluck the appropriate SQL from the array and use it.  so what I would propose is something like this

```
$sortIndex = $_POST["sort"];

$sortMap = array(
"ORDER BY date_added DESC",
"ORDER BY date_added ASC",
"ORDER BY name ASC",
"ORDER BY name DESC",
"ORDER BY stat_clicked DESC"
);
$sortDesc = array(
"Sort by date added in descending order",
"Sort by date added in ascending order",
"Sort by name in ascending order",
"Sort by name in descending order",
"Sort by number of clicks in desending order"
);

$sortType = isset($sortMap[$sortIndex]) 
    ? $sortMap[$sortIndex] 
    : "ORDER BY date_added ASC";

<select name="sort">
    <?php foreach($sortDesc as $k=>$text): ?>
    <option value="<?=$k?>" <?=$sortType==$k?"selected='selected'":""?> ><?=$text?></option>
    <?php endforeach?>
</select>
```

if you had something similar to this in the page, then you can show the text strings inside the [select] and when one is selected+posted, it'll select the appropriate type from the arrays setup, obviously I haven't tested this in an actual page, I'm ad-libbing, but I think you can understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: before somebody else says it, you can combine $sortMap with $sortDesc by putting an array("ORDER BY name DESC","Sort by name in desending order") and using the [0] and [1] array indexes to say whether you want to use the sql or the text description.